# fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/refs/heads/xxxbranch' when cherrypick Revision in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

RT:
rest api:

```
'POST /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/cherrypick'
```

errors:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/refs/heads/xxxbranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

how to resolve this error?thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's something wrong with your request body. What is your "destination" field value?

I was able to correctly cherry pick a change with the following command:

```
curl --request POST -d@- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/REVISION-NUMBER/cherrypick <<EOF
{
    "message": "Test Cherrypick using REST",
    "destination": "feature3"
}
EOF
```

Comment: thanks,and the destination is "refs/heads/xxxbranch"

Comment: Is the branch name "xxxbranch"? So... use "xxxbranch" in the destination field instead of "refs/heads/xxxbranch".